# 30 minute error in Java date calculation in year 1900 only

Tags: java, time, calendar

```
package check;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // length of a day
        long DAY_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());

        cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + DAY_MILLIS);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

And it's result is:

```
Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 KST 1900
Mon Jan 01 23:30:00 KST 1900 // Where is 30 minutes here?
```

Most funny and important clue is that this problem happens when year is 1900 only.

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/732016)?

Comment: Definitely related.  Same basic problem ... time is complicated.

Comment: I tried this and I get `Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1900`. Something to do with time zones?

Comment: I got Mon Jan 01 23:39:52 EET 1900

Comment: Works correctly for me too.  A better question might be, what broken version of Java are you running?  I'm using 1.7.0_21 on windows.

Comment: Anyone who knows off the top of their head the complete list of Local Time Discontinuities (What is KST anyways?) between 1899 to now has my sympathy and my respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of historical GMT offset changes. See an example here http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=101&syear=1900. These changes are different for different time zones. For instance in my time zone (EET) the result  of your test is different:

```
Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 1900
Mon Jan 01 23:39:52 EET 1900
```

because (according to Java) clocks were turned forward 0:20:08 hours on 1 Jan 1900 in EET. TimeZone has methods to determine offset for a particular date, TimeZone.getOffset(long date)  API

*This method returns a historically correct offset value if an underlying TimeZone implementation subclass supports historical Daylight Saving Time schedule and GMT offset changes.*

Note that if you set Calendar to GMT and print the result in GMT there will be no error.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.set(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

output

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00
1900-01-02 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Such irregularities in processing dates are common.  See e.g. [Jon Skeet's most famous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1339987)  I'm looking for the actual database of these glitches; will update answer when found.

This answer is fairly incomplete but may be enough to get you unstuck; I'll leave it but encourage you to accept a more complete one if posted.

Comment: Wow epic fun Skeet answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // length of a day
        long DAY_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println(DAY_MILLIS);
        System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis() + DAY_MILLIS);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() + DAY_MILLIS);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
```

> Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 1900
>
> -2209017599564
>
> 86400000
>
> -2208931199564
>
> Tue Jan 02 00:05:52 CST 1900

It seems .getTimeInMillis() is returning a value that is different from what you expect.

> getTimeInMillis
>
> public long getTimeInMillis()
>
> Returns this Calendar's time value in milliseconds.
>
> Returns: the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.